# Add Attribute to XMLROOT ElementName

Tags: c#, xml, elementname, xmlroot

I have a class with the class attribute :

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "RootXML")]
public class Apply
{
    /My Properties
}
```

now to create an xml from the above class I use below function :

```
public virtual string RenderXml()
{

    XmlTextWriter writer = null;
    try
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        writer = new XmlTextWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8);
        writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", "");
        _xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, this, ns);
        ms.Position = 0;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms))
        {
            return sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (writer != null)
            writer.Close();
    }
}
```

My question is how do i add attributes to "RootXML" and read the value of attribute from config file and from function e.g.

```
<RootXML attr1="read from config" attr2="read from function" >
    <Property1>value</Property1>
</RootXML>
```

Comment: Did you try this :`writer.WriteAttributeString("AttrNAme", "AttrValue");`

Comment: tried this : writer.WriteAttributeString("RootXML", "attr1=" + System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["id"]); but get exception :  threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException

Comment: what was the stack trace.

Comment: at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces)
   at PDB.UK.UI.ApplyInfoContainer.RenderXml() in C:\Proj\Container.cs:line 227
   at btnSubmit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Proj\Project\Create.aspx.cs:line 185

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add to your class property attribute `[XmlAttribute]` and that property will be serilized as attribute

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "RootXML")]
public class Apply
{
    private string _testAttr="dfdsf";



    [XmlAttribute]
    public String TestAttr
    {
        get { return _testAttr; }

        set { _testAttr = value; }
    }
}
```

Serialization result for that class

```
<RootXML TestAttr="dfdsf" />
```

Added for last comment.
If i understand correctly you need to have only one key in session. If it true, that you can use something like that:

```
string GetKey(){

      if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Session["mySessionKey"].ToString()))
                HttpContext.Current.Session["mySessionKey"] = GenereteKey();
      return HttpContext.Current.Session["mySessionKey"].ToString();

}
```

Comment: It works, but got a question.I called a static function like so : private string _testAttr= GetKey(); which will generate a guid and put it in HttpContext.Current.Session...my question is, would this create one key per session?

Comment: @Sam,see answer fix. This is what you need?